# Server side processing of url query mydomain.com/myscrip.php/word

Tags: url

Simple question: I see URL queries in the format mydomain.com/myscript.php/word without question mark (?) but I don't find how to make php process it.

mydomain.com/myscript.php/word

Answer (score 0):

You can use a webserver to redirect certain traffic to specific files.

e.g. https://serverfault.com/questions/45552/how-do-i-make-all-urls-run-through-a-single-php-file